# Developing customized form and workflow with only visual Studio 2010

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, form

I am trying to duplicate a Domino workflow onto sharepoint 2010.

The domino workflow that I am trying to port over consist of many section, fields and button. As such I thought of using ASP.NET to create the UI, with an underlying List to store the values and state machine workflow to capture the status.m

Most of the article I read teaches to use Infopath 2010 to create the UI, and uses Visual 2010 to modify the codes to bind custom actions.

However I do not have Infopath 2010, only VS2010. I wonder if anybody have experience in creating such solution without the use of Infopath.

-------------------------- Edit ----------------------------------
Sharepoint MVP, thank you for your response.

I'm attempting to create workflow, using form to record the detail of requester request information, approval remarks and decision, implementation remarks and if it is completed as well as the review by the requester when the task is completed.
For example, a workflow to record the process from requesting a new feature details, to approval remarks and decision, to implementer remarks and progress, to review remarks.

The form might consists of several section, fields and button. 
For example, 
a Requester Section with the following fields and button
Name :
Phone :
Feature to introduce:
Attachment if any:
[Button : Send for Approval ]

I am wondering if it is possible to be implemented in Sharepoint2010 with only Visual 2010

Comment: Is this a question? Many of us here have created workflows with ASP.NET forms - I only do ASP.NET forms for instance. Please update your post with a real question or a real problem.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is possible. actually VS2010 is the most powerfull dev tool for SharePoint, and you can do everything with this tool only. Regarding workflows, this means that you have to use ASP.NET forms instead of Infopath.
Please see the examples:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811589(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811589%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

http://rshelton.com/archive/2007/10/05/sharepoint-document-workflow-with-visual-studio-workshop-documents-download.aspx

As you can see, these articles are from SP2007 but worklow forms development process is pretty much the same.